# Android - how to have 'underline'?

Tags: android

How can I achieve this (or something like this)?
Looking for some 'underlines' that will be the width of the element. 
Was thinking a drawable but I'm not too sure how that would work with stretching and what not. Thanks.

[image]

**Edit**

Made a new XML file and included it under every title, works great.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/layout_underline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:background="@color/layout_underline" />

</merge>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it by create view in XML as below :

```
  <View 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
      android:layout_height="2dp" />
```

and you can customize it as you need,

hope help you

Comment: This is the kinda thing I was looking for thanks but both answers work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 9-patch image and set it as the background of your TextViews.

Here's the 9-patch resource page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch